# Trying to serialize SelectMultipleField with DjangoChoices on DRF

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm developing an API Rest with Django Rest Framework to be consumed by an AngularJS app. I've got some models with attributes which are [`SelectMultipleField`](https://github.com/kelvinwong-ca/django-select-multiple-field), but I've got a problem when I'm trying to update that fields via JSON with my API.

When I get the data from the server, I'm receiving an array of strings, but when I sent the updated data back to the server with the same format, I'm getting an error: `"This isn't a valid option"`. I've also tried to parse the data to strings splited by commas but it doesn't work either.... Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong?

Models:

```
class Hueco(models.Model):

    class ProteccionType(DjangoChoices):
        Ninguno = ChoiceItem(label=u'Ninguno', value='ninguno')
        Retranqueo = ChoiceItem(label=u'Retranqueo', value='retranqueo')
        Voladizo = ChoiceItem(label=u'Voladizo', value='voladizo')
        Lateral_izquierdo = ChoiceItem(label=u'Lateral Izquierdo', value='lateral_izquierdo')
        Lateral_derecho = ChoiceItem(label=u'Lateral Derecho', value='lateral_derecho')
        Toldo = ChoiceItem(label=u'Toldo', value='toldo')
        Lamas_verticales = ChoiceItem(label=u'Lamas Verticales', value='lamas_verticales')
        Lamas_horizontales = ChoiceItem(label=u'Lamas Horizontales', value='lamas_horizontales')
        Laminas = ChoiceItem(label=u'Láminas', value='laminas')
        Cortinas = ChoiceItem(label=u'Cortinas', value='cortinas')

    tipo_proteccion = SelectMultipleField(
        max_length=150,
        choices=ProteccionType.choices,
        default=ProteccionType.Ninguno
    )
```

Serializers:

```
class HuecoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Hueco
        fields = ('id', 'tipo_proteccion' )
```

So, an example of the JSON I'm getting from the server could be:

```
[
    "id": 1,
    "tipo_proteccion": [
      "ninguno"
    ]
]
```

And if I try to update the data with this one I get the error:

```
[
    "id": 1,
    "tipo_proteccion": [
      "cortinas",
      "voladizo"
    ]
]
```

But if I send it like this it goes ok.

```
[
    "id": 1,
    "tipo_proteccion": "cortinas"
]
```

So my problem it's how to send more than one choice. I think it's because I need to change the way I serialize it, but not sure...

Comment: MultipleChoiceField is what the serializer be given too.  Read here [link](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#multiplechoicefield) .

Comment: Finally we fixed it adding that `MultipleChoiceField` in the Serializer and adding `encode_list_to_csv` when `create` and `update`. Thank you.